# Tomcat and compression: CSS/JS compression works ... sometimes

Tags: javascript, css, tomcat

I have a strange problem with my Tomcat 7 (both on Ubuntu and on Windows 7, no Apache in front of Tomcat) compressing CSS/JS.

It works sometimes:
I have a big third party CSS (comprising of Bootstrap, Angular) and JS (Bootstrap, Angular, JQuery), which is NOT compressed. Tomcat doesn't send an

```
content-encoding: gzip
```

But my very own CSS/JS are gzipped, as they should (Tomcat sends an content-encoding: gzip to browser in this case).

So this is the **server.xml** of my Tomcat:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
            connectionTimeout="20000"
            redirectPort="8443" 
            compression="force"
            compressionMinSize="2048"
            compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,application/javascript,text/css"/>
```

So in short:
js/thirdParty.js is uncompressed: FAIL!, 
js/own.js is compressed: OK

What could be the reason behind that?

Thanks,
Bernhard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it out by myself. I have to add the attribute

```
useSendfile="false"
```

to the `Connector` tag. If I don't, Tomcat will not compress
files greather than 48kb (when I use NIO, which is standard for Tomcat7+).